# WebStorm treats working statement $@ as an error in .less file

Tags: less, webstorm

I've created a mixin that looks like this:

```
.elem( @map1, @name ){
  @color: @map1[color];
  color: @map2[$@color];
}
```

WebStorm underlines dollar sign $ as an error (and all the path to the file). Everything works in the project, but this makes me anxious whether I've followed the best practices or not.

Does anybody know how to safely get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This LESS feature is not yet supported, please follow [WEB-39083](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39083) for updates

Comment: Got it. Thank you!